# Cannot pass/bind command to WPF user control

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, command, dependency-properties

I'm trying to pass a command to an element in a WPF user control.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MyControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <!-- shortened -->
    <Button Command="{Binding Command}">
        <Button.Content>
            <!-- shortened -->
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty
      = DependencyProperty.Register("Command", 
                                           typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyControl));
   //shortened        
   public ICommand Command
   {
      get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
      set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
   }
   //shortened
}
```

```
<uc:MyControl Command="{Binding DoStuffCommand}" />  <!-- shortened -->
```

When the button in the user control is clicked, nothing happens.
When I debug, the `Command` property is null.
Binding the command to a button outside of the user control does work.
What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 8):

The default `DataContext` for your `Button` is your UserControl's `DataContext`, not your UserControl, so you are trying to bind to `DataContext.Command` instead of `UserControl.Command`

To bind to `UserControl.Command`, use a `RelativeSource` binding

```
<Button Command="{Binding Command, RelativeSource={
        RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControl}}}">
```

**EDIT** Just noticed [HB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957123/cannot-pass-bind-command-to-wpf-user-control/7957233#7957233), which would also work. Usually I prefer `RelativeSource` bindings to `ElementName` ones because sometimes I rename items and used to forget what other controls reference that item by Name

Comment: I forgot to mention that the **user control constructor** looks like this:
`code`
        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
`code`
Another binding element, a string field works just fine, it's the command that won't work.
Am I simming something?

Comment: Also as I mentioned the **Command property in the user control** is **null** when debugged. The command does exist and binding it to a button in stead of the user control does work.

Comment: @David Does the command work correctly if you use the `RelativeSource` binding I have in my answer instead of the simple binding you have in your question?

Comment: @David Use a tool like `Snoop` on your application while it is running and take a look at what the `DataContext` for both your UserControl and your Button. It can probably give you a clue as to where your binding is failing. http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5):

Name the control and use `ElementName`:

```
<UserControl ...
             Name="control">
    <Button Command="{Binding Command, ElementName=control}">
    <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: Please view the reply on Rachel's post

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would just bind to the command from the host control/window.  Because the data context will be inherited from it.  Something like this.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MyControl" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"> 
    <!-- shortened --> 
    <Button Command="{Binding DoStuffCommand}"> 
        <Button.Content> 
            <!-- shortened --> 
        </Button.Content> 
    </Button> 
</UserControl>
```

Then you can remove the dependency property code from the code-behind file.

And remove the command property binding,

```
<uc:MyControl />
```

Comment: Bad idea because the UserControl might not necessarily have a `DoStuffCommand` in it's DataContext

Comment: Obviously if the property is not there for the data context it would not work.  However, I disagree that it is a bad idea.  You would need more information to determine if it is really a bad idea.  I was just trying to provide a solution to the problem.

Comment: I guess its not a problem if you expect this `UserControl` to always be used with a specific `ViewModel`, however I feel it's a bad idea if this UserControl is part of a Control library

Comment: I can understand that. I also think the simplfied data binding expression and removing the depencey property from the user control code-behind actually makes it less complex which I like.

Comment: I agree with Brad, you can either set the ElementName property or define the delegate command in the consumer code's view model with the same name (DoStuffCommand).

Answer (score 0):

In general, I always follow Rachel advice (like the [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7957830/968003) above). But in this particular case, I'd consider setting `DataContext` on the root element of the user control, then it'd make a neat binding in there.

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
<!-- shortened -->
    <Button Command="{Binding Command}">
        <Button.Content>
            <!-- shortened -->
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</Grid >
```